# How to share data between view controllers that are not directly connected by segues

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

[image]

What is the best strategy for the data that user inputs in the text field in the view controller indicated here as 1,to be sent to View Controller 2? The two views are not directly connected by segues.

Should that be handled using a delegate? If so, which object would be the delegate and which would be delegating?

Could sending data from 1 to 2 be achieved by keeping the reference to the object 2 in the object 1 and invoking a method accepting data from 1 on 2? In fact I tried it and it works. But is it the proper way to share data between view controllers?

Or maybe, is it possible to place a datasource in the main AppDelegate? If yes, how?

Comment: Short hacky way... id viewController = self.tabBarController.viewControllers[1];

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is "it depends".

Yes, you can have view controller 1 maintain a pointer to view controller 2 and set up a protocol to communicate information. However, view controller 2 might not exist a the time view controller 1 collects the information. or you might not want view controller 1 to have to know about view controller 2.

I would probably set up an app-wide data container singleton. (Do a search on the singleton design pattern in Objective C, here on SO or on Google if you're not familiar with it.) Then set up properties for the information you want to make global. You can add persistence to the data container object quite easily, and then you have a central repository for state data across your app.

Comment: It seemed obvious to me that a central repository for data to be shared across the app must exist. I just didn't know what to look for. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple ways to handle it, here would be the easiest method using `NSNotificationCenter`.

When you want to send the text in `ViewController1` do this:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"textDidUpdateNotification" object:nil userInfo:@{@"textKey": yourTextField.text}];
```

In `ViewController2` have this:

```
- (void)textDidUpdate:(NSNotification*)notification {
    NSString *theText = [[notification userInfo] objectForKey:@"textKey"];
}


- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(textDidUpdate:) name:@"textDidUpdateNotification" object:nil];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could try NSUserDefaults.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsuserdefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html

It's something I use a lot. :D

Answer (score 1):

Tipically you have 3 ways:

1. Using `NSUserDefaults` (Naife solution, easy but not elegant. And the problem is that you have to remember to delete this data or remains on the sandbox forever)
2. Using `SQLite` i.e. using database (not good if you have few data)
3. Using a singleton class that handle the data you need. (Probably if you need to pass data to view controller to another, this data represents somethings in your app that sounds like a "session data", so is correct put in a "Session singleton". This data are not persistent like `NSUserDefaults` so you don't have to remember to delete them).

Even a 4th ways is possible, and you mentioned in your question "using the delegate". This solution works like the 3rd way (singleton): i.e. `UIApplicationDelegate` is a singleton instance, but the problem is that you put in the app delegate a data that not represent the app delegate: you put them in app delegate only for convenience, but you are losing the code modeling and your code are not so good and clear like with 3rd solution.
For information, you can access to app delegate everywhere in you code with this 2 lines:

```
 1. #import "AppDelegate.h";
 2. AppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll give singletons a try.